# The formula of the order of multistep methods

Tags: numerical-methods

How can I derive this $$(1+\xi) \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\xi-\frac{1}{12}\xi^{2}\right)+O(\xi^3)$$ from
$$\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^{2}}+O(\xi^3)$$
?

The whole formula is below. This is from "A first course in the numerical analysis of differential equations by Arieh Iserles"
$$\frac{\rho(w)}{\ln w}=\frac{\xi+\xi^{2}}{\xi-\frac{1}{2}\xi^2+\frac{1}{3}\xi^{3}+O(\xi^4)}=
\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^{2}}+O(\xi^3)
$$

$$=(1+\xi) \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\xi-\frac{1}{12}\xi^{2}\right)+O(\xi^3)=1+\frac{3}{2}\xi+\frac{5}{12}\xi^{2}+(\xi^3)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the series $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+O(x^3)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1-\frac12\xi+\frac13\xi^2}
&=1+\left(\frac12\xi-\frac13\xi^2\right)+\left(\frac12\xi-\frac13\xi^2\right)^2+O(\xi^3)\\
&=1+\frac12\xi-\frac13\xi^2+\frac14\xi^2+O(\xi^3)\\
&=1+\frac12\xi-\frac1{12}\xi^2+O(\xi^3)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Now I can move on:)

Answer (score 2):

Take the Taylor expansion of
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}\xi+\frac{1}{3}\xi^2}$$
around $0$ and insert. All the terms of order greater than $2$ are absorbed in the $O(\xi^3)$ part.